How to Sufficiently Downgrade the X-Server Version for Ubuntu 24.10 to Allow GF210 Video Card Driver Installation from the Manufacturer's Site
I am able to access DVI-D in safe graphics mode (here) but I want a better installation of the driver to get access to the HDMI port.
From lspci:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce G210] (rev a2)

"1. The first, and most obvious, is to just to downgrade to 14.04."
Ubuntu ... AMD Graphics has some suggestions, but unfortunately the downgrade of the X-Server does not seem to currently work with Ubuntu 24.10 LTS
With the most current version of the Ubuntu 24.10 LTS operating system, then, how can the X-server be downgraded and the driver be installed to allow the HDMI port to work?
Please assist.

A downgrade of major components is not easy, unless you have very good coding skills. Don't think there is a manual for it. I'd try Ubuntu-pro with the 18.04 release. It has reached the end of standard support, which takes it beyond the scope of this site, but it might have nvidia-304 available, and is free for personal use. Here is a link 18.04.1.iso
